# Change the color temperature of monitor using java JNA Win32API

Tags: java, winapi, jna

I would like to create a software similar to redshift for linux that gradually shifts the screen color temperature to more red tint. I would like to use java native access and win32 api functions to do this.

Currently Ive tried changing the windows register's correlating to
"Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\CloudStore\Store\DefaultAccount\Current\default$windows.data.bluelightreduction.bluelightreductionstate\windows.data.bluelightreduction.bluelightreductionstate" without much effect.

Ive also tinkered with [Dxva2](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/237206727cab3cdfd0285ed57035ab3b64179ed4/contrib/platform/src/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/Dxva2.java#L230) SetMonitorColorTemperature() function, but cannot find how I am supposed to get the HANDLE parameter.

below is my code:

```
import com.sun.jna.Library;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg;
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.Platform;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.BOOL;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HDC;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.HMONITOR;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Dxva2;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.HighLevelMonitorConfigurationAPI.MC_COLOR_TEMPERATURE;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLE;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.HANDLEByReference;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.POINT.ByValue;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.PhysicalMonitorEnumerationAPI.PHYSICAL_MONITOR;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;

class ChangeColorTemp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("helo");
        ByValue pt = new ByValue(); 
        pt.x = 0;
        pt.y = 0;
        int dwFlags = User32.MONITOR_DEFAULTTONEAREST;
        HMONITOR hMonitor = User32.INSTANCE.MonitorFromPoint(pt, dwFlags);
        HANDLE hMonitorHandle = new HANDLE(new Pointer(hMonitor));
        
        Dxva2.INSTANCE.SetMonitorColorTemperature(hMonitorHandle, MC_COLOR_TEMPERATURE.MC_COLOR_TEMPERATURE_4000K);
        
    }
}
```

I would like to know if I am going about this the right way, just to get used to Win32API.
Many thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for [`SetMonitorColorTemperature`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi/nf-highlevelmonitorconfigurationapi-setmonitorcolortemperature) says:

> `[in] hMonitor`
>
> Handle to a physical monitor. To get the monitor handle, call [`GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/physicalmonitorenumerationapi/nf-physicalmonitorenumerationapi-getphysicalmonitorsfromhmonitor) or [`GetPhysicalMonitorsFromIDirect3DDevice9`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/physicalmonitorenumerationapi/nf-physicalmonitorenumerationapi-getphysicalmonitorsfromidirect3ddevice9).

Further, it identifies the type of that handle as `HANDLE`.

In your code you've called [MonitorFromPoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-monitorfrompoint) which returns a `HMONITOR`, but you're simply changing the type of that pointer with your call to `HANDLE hMonitorHandle = new HANDLE(new Pointer(hMonitor));`.

Instead, you need to use that `HMONITOR` as one of the arguments to `GetPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR` to match it up to a physical monitor.  You'll get a pointer to a [`PHYSICAL_MONITOR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/physicalmonitorenumerationapi/ns-physicalmonitorenumerationapi-physical_monitor) structure, whose `HANDLE` is what you need to send to `SetMonitorColorTemperature`.  You can see an example of this in the JNA [MonitorInfoDemo](https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/blob/master/contrib/monitordemo/src/com/sun/jna/contrib/demo/MonitorInfoDemo.java#L100) class.

A readability suggestion.  Having `ByValue` in your code without it being obvious it's a `POINT` is confusing.  And while it won't change the end result, you might consider using the constructor for `POINT` that takes the parameters instead of assigning them later.  I'd suggest:

```java
POINT.ByValue pt = new POINT.ByValue(0, 0);
```

Comment: Thank you man, ive seen that page, though only in brief glances. Didn't know the API can be read like that. Cheers for the help